# Android - Cant read file, getting exception

Tags: java, android, file, fileinputstream

i have an issue which is driving me crazy.
So I have two methods, one for reading and the other for writing.
I have a class called `Converastion` which holds an `ArrayList<ChatMessage>` and some `String` properties. Both `Converastion` and `ChatMessage` implements `Serializable` and I have I know I can save this `Conversation` object to the `FileSystem`.

But when I try to read this and then write it (update the `Conversation`), it doesn't work quite well. The issue is on reading, I always get the `java.io.EOFException` when I know the `Conversation` object always has been written before.

Here are the my two methods:

```
public Conversation getConversation(String userId, boolean createByDefault){
        try {
            File f = new File(sApplicationContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + "Conversation" + "/" + userId);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Conversation ret = (Conversation) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            return ret;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Conversation conv = new Conversation();
            conv.userId = userId;
            conv.usernameChat = userId + "@" + XMPPController.HOST;

            if(createByDefault)
                setConversation(conv);

            return conv;
        }
    }

    public void setConversation(Conversation conv){
        try {
            File dir = new File(sApplicationContext.getFilesDir(), "Conversation");
            if(!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
            }           
            File newFile = new File(sApplicationContext.getFilesDir(), "Conversation" + "/" + conv.userId);
            newFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(conv);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Now I use these methods in a loop, which causes the problem. `onListIQ` calles multiple times rapedly, a listener called from another class. I even tried to set `synchronized(this)` but no luck, here's the code:

```
public void onListIQ(ListChatIQ listIQ){
    // get the conversation
                        Conversation conv = getConversation(listIQ.userId, true);

                        // loop through messages
                        for(ChatIQ chat : listIQ.chatIqs){
                            // determine if message was from me or other user
                            String userId = listIQ.userId;
                            if(chat.fromMe){
                                userId = currentProfile.userId;
                            }

                            // create new message
                            ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();
                            cm.id = messageId;
                            cm.userId = userId;
                            cm.text = body;
                            cm.date = new Date();

                            // add message
                            conv.messages.add(cm);
                        }

                        // update the conversation with messages
                        setConversation(conv);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try maybe adding fis.close() after in.close() and fos.close() after out.close() in your methods. Probably the position in file remains set at EOF(last position of file) and when reading again - the second time - you get EOF exception because you are at the end of the file.

Comment: @Reshi File does not have any method close().

Comment: yes I badly read... ive edited my comment

Comment: @Reshi I tried fis.close and fos.close, but the problem still remains!

Comment: Other two methods that could work could be to set fis.getChannel().position(0);  or fis.reset();  . Of course the same for fos variable in setConversation method.

Comment: call reset and set position before youread or write your data.

Comment: @Reshi reset throws IOException.

Comment: IOException when reset is called occurs when the stream is closed or when something other happnes. Have you tried deleting reset method and leaving only fis.getChannel().position(0); and fos.getChannel().position(0); ? These statements should go after FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);  and after FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(newFile);

If this doesnt help I have no idea then :) I had similar problem in Java SE and also in android but the set position and rest worked in SE and set position worked in android hm

Comment: @Reshi yes I added getChannel().position(0) at both fis and fos after I init them. And no exception, but the problem still remains! I have no idea either why!

Comment: @Reshi EOFException always at second time, and random time.

Comment: Do you flush(), after writing?

Comment: @Tobor No I don't. Do I need to do it?

Comment: I think it doesn't finalize the writing until you flush the stream. This is possibly why the file is found empty.

Comment: @Tobor: I will try this. Also, I don't need to set the position of the file to 0?

Comment: No. You're creating your file. It starts from 0 and goes on. Well, when I do my file readings/writings i never explicitly set a position.

Comment: @Tobor: I tried out.flush() after out.writeObject(). But still the same issue. Doesn't this have to do that I'm reading and then writing in a loop?

Comment: I normally read all at once and write all at once (joining or splitting with "\n" as the separator). What if you copied your file, so that you read from one copy and write to the other? then delete the temporary copy (the "reading"). It could be another idea, not to overwrite the file while you read it.

Comment: @Tobor Hmm that would be one approach yes, I have a lot of Convesation objects throughout the application. So I made another solution, which is creating an LRUCache to get the temp, and then I always write to file and only read from file when it doesn't exist in cache. And it seems to work good, but I would have wanted to implement it without the LRU solution.